# how to to bridge two networks and packet alteration

Tags: networking, iptables, bridge, forwarding

I am trying to bridge two networks (i.e. 20.20.10.0/24 and 20.20.20.0/24). I have a machine (Ubuntu 16.04) connected to both networks and my ultimate goal is this machine to act as a bridge between the two networks while allowing me to modify packets at will.

I have followed the indications here (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge) and sucessfully managed to bridge the two networks, using this configuration I am clueless on how to modify packets.

I have tried the following python script without sucess (https://gist.github.com/mgalgs/1856631) and also tried to use IPtables to route and forward packets.

I just need some advice on how to proceed, what would be the best way to bridge to networks and allow the modification of packets travelling the network?

Comment: Do you want to bridge the networks or to route from one network to the other? Those two options are entirely different and work at different levels. For example, bridging works at the data link level and has no notion of packets.

Comment: I am not that versed in this topic, but I would like to alter packets so I guess I want to route them?